# How to download google code from SVN onto Mac

Tags: ios, macos, svn, download, google-api

I'd like to download the Google APIs Objective-C client onto my Mac (OSX 10.8).  [This page](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/source/checkout) states the following:

> Non-members may check out a read-only working copy anonymously over HTTP.
>   svn checkout http://google-api-objectivec-client.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ google-api-objectivec-client-read-only

So I tried running that line in Terminal, and all I got was:

> -bash: svn: command not found

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?  SVN should be installed already with OSX, no?  Or do I need to install it first?  Do SVN commands work in any directory?

Any help, much appreciated.  Thanks guys.

Comment: Sounds like you should get behind [Issue 810](https://code.google.com/p/support/issues/detail?id=810)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you need Apple's command line tools. You can get these by either installing Xcode from the Mac App Store or downloading the command line tools from [here](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action).

Comment: THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU.  I downloaded the Mountain Lion command line tools from that link and it's now downloading my source.  Much appreciated!

Comment: Some time you don't need to install that tool separately. When you will run svn command on terminal, and if that tool is not present then OS X it self will prompt you for the message and will suggest you to install Xcode tool.

Answer (score 3):

How to install Command Line Tools:

Xcode / Behaviors /  Edit behaviors... / Downloads / Command Line Tools / Install

Comment: This is no longer the case in Xcode 5.  It is now Xcode/Preferences.../Downloads